# error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'double' and 'double *')

Tags: c

I have an error in this code:

```
mat mat_y(mat b, mat l, int n) {
    mat c = c = mat_new(n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        c[i]=b[i];
        for(j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            c[i] -= l[i][j] * c[j];
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

The error:

> invalid operands to binary * (have 'double' and 'double *')

Here are some information:

```
typedef double **mat;
int i,j,k;
void mat_zero(mat x, int n) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            x[i][j] = 0;
}


mat mat_new(int n) {
    mat x = malloc(sizeof(double*) * n);
    x[0] = malloc(sizeof(double) * n * n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x[i] = x[0] + n * i;
    mat_zero(x, n);

    return x;
}
```

Comment: Your types aren't lining up. You're trying to mix up a pointer to a double and a double. Which line is it complaining about?

Comment: `c[j]` is a pointer to double. Is anything unclear about the message?

Comment: `mat_new` is messed up.  You are allocating a two-dimensional array incorrectly; it's an unholy mix of an array of arrays and a one-dimensional array using math to determine the columns.

Comment: It is not a good idea to hide pointers in `typedef`. It leads to confusion.

Comment: And use braces in the `for` loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary operator `*` cannot multiply a pointer and a double. It appears from your code though you are not actually trying to multiply a pointer but are incorrectly accessing a double pointer.

```
c[i] -= l[i][j] * c[j];
```

So for pointers like `double**`, it means *pointer to a pointer*. If you only access it once, like `c[i]`, this dereferences the outer pointer which results in a pointer to a double. You need to dereference a `double**` twice in order to access the floating point number in it.